# How can I play each sound when a key/button is clicked?

Tags: javascript

I am messing with this exercise where a sound is played depending on which key you press (N, S, B or F).

I would also like to play each sound when the button is clicked, so it also works for mobile and the user has another option to play the sounds. What is the best way to approach this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Key sounds</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>


  <div class="keys">
    <div data-key="78" class="key">
      <kbd>N</kbd>
      <span class="sound">nani</span>
    </div>
    <div data-key="83" class="key">
      <kbd>S</kbd>
      <span class="sound">scrambling</span>
    </div>
    <div data-key="66" class="key">
      <kbd>B</kbd>
      <span class="sound">barber</span>
    </div>
    <div data-key="70" class="key">
      <kbd>F</kbd>
      <span class="sound">face</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <audio data-key="78" src="sounds/nani.m4a"></audio>
  <audio data-key="83" src="sounds/scrambling.m4a"></audio>
  <audio data-key="66" src="sounds/barber.m4a"></audio>
  <audio data-key="70" src="sounds/chap.m4a"></audio>

  <script>
    function playSound(e) {
      const audio = document.querySelector(`audio[data-key="${e.keyCode}"]`);
      const key = document.querySelector(`.key[data-key="${e.keyCode}"]`);
      if(!audio) return; // stop the function from running all together
      audio.currentTime = 0; // rewind to the start
      audio.play();
      key.classList.add('playing');
    }

    function removeTransition(e) {
      if(e.propertyName !== 'transform') return; // skip it if it's not a transform
      this.classList.remove('playing');
    }

    const keys = document.querySelectorAll('.key');
    keys.forEach(key => key.addEventListener('transitionend', removeTransition));
    window.addEventListener('keydown', playSound);
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you be more specific in your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could extend your code with the following:

```
keys.forEach(element => {

   // Add a click event listener to each ".key" element, so that
   // clicking plays the corresponding audio
   element.addEventListener('click', () => {

       // Fetch the key for the audio object that matches the key of 
       // this element
       const audioKey = element.getAttribute('data-key');

       // Query the document for the audio object corresponding to 
       // this element's key. 

       // The document.querySelector will get the first element from 
       // the document that matches the selector you pass. 

       // The audio[data-key="${ audioKey } part means "get an audio 
       // element that has a data-key attrbitute whose value matches 
       // that of the current element's "data-key" (ie 78, 83, etc)

       const audio = document.querySelector(`audio[data-key="${ audioKey }"]`);

       // Play the audio in the same way as you currently are
       audio.currentTime = 0;
       audio.play();
       element.classList.add('playing');
   })
})
```

Comment: Thank you! What is `document.querySelector(audio[data-key="${ key.getAttribute('data-key') }"]);` doing exactly?

Comment: Hi there, you're welcome - please see my updated answer. Hope this offers some clarification :-)

Comment: I really appreciate your effort explaining to me, thanks a lot again!